# change multiple files content by the file name

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed

I have few file, the name of the files if `vhost-<someport>.conf`, I want to replace the line with the port number in each file by the filename $port `vhost-$port.conf`.

For example `vhost-8081.conf` file will contain the line `listen 8081`, `vhost-8082.conf` file will contain the line `listen 8082;`, etc..

```
vhost-8081.conf
vhost-8082.conf
etc..

server {
    listen 8081;
    }

server {
    listen 8082;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have files named `vhost-NUM.conf`, then you can strip the `vhost-` prefix and the `.conf` suffix to extract the port number, and then use `sed -i` to replace `listen .*` with the number in-place, updating the file:

```
for file in vhost-*.conf; do
    num=${file#vhost-}
    num=${num%.conf}
    sed -i "s/listen .*/listen $num;/" "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want:

```
    for file in vhost-*.conf
    do     num=${file#vhost-}
    sed -i  "s/listen .*/vhost-$num;/" "$file"
    done

    cat vhost*
    server {
    vhost-8081.conf;
    }
    server {
    vhost-8082.conf;
```